# Bottom-sheet is hidden behind the soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheet in my app and the user needs to enter some data using the soft keyboard. However, when the soft keyboard appears, the bottom sheet is hidden behind the same. I would like the same to be pushed upwards, whenever soft keyboard appears.

I have added the following in the manifest.

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Here is the XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_selected_font"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Choose a font"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Select"
        android:tooltipText="Tap to select"

       />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_f_chicken"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However, the same is not working. Your help/support would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your bottomsheet layout with a scrollview, had the same issue and the scrollview did the trick. You can also provide your xml, so that we can provide additional help

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have updated the query with the XML.

Comment: Have you tried making the scroll view the parent layout?